# In python can we save CSV file given by user given name?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, getopt

I need to save/write a csv file from pandas dataframe in python. I have tried the following way;

```
import sys
import getopt
import os
def usage():
    print "-f Please provide input file"

in1_flag = False
out_flag = True
inFile1 = ""
outFile1 = ""

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'i:o', ['input_file1=', 'out_file1='])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ('-i', '--input_file1'):
       inFile1 = os.path.abspath(arg)
       in1_flag = True
    elif opt in ('-o', '--out_file1'):
       outFile1 = os.path.abspath(arg)
split_h = []
with open(inFile1) as ff:
    for line in ff:
        split_h = line.split()

import pandas as pd
d1 = {'report': split_h}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d1, columns=['report'])
df1.to_csv(outFile1, sep = '\t',header = False, index= False)
```

I thought it would be as easy as taking input but here I am stuck at writing file.

Comment: your code is incomplete, please read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Is it so? But I have shown how  I created flag for outfile to how I tried to write file from pandas dataframe to csv. I perceive there is some error in last line of code.

Comment: try to run provided snippet and see what happens (hint: `SyntaxError`)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Here I have edited the code. Thanks and it would be great If you could help me out.

Comment: so what problem are you struggling with? describe input/desired output

Comment: I want my dataframe df1 to save in the file which is given by user by -o [output_file_name].